# How to detect if a toggle is open it should be displayed on a larger screen jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

this is my first post.I am working with different size screens.On a visible-sm screen such as an ipad/mobile when i click a button it toggles a div for me.However i would like to know if my toggle/div is opened while it is in visible-sm mode and i make the screen "responsive" how do i get it to toggle my div  over the entire screen.Only if its open.

code

```
function Toggle() {
          if  ($("#btn").click(function () {

                ($("#open").toggle());           //this will display my "#open div"
                ($("#open").css('display', 'block'));
                $("#div").hide();
            }))
            else if{
                    ($("#open").is(":visible"))
                {
                  alert("need a holiday!!!"); //this is what i tried to check if the div is open but it does not detect anything
                   }
             // so if #open is opened and the screen is now responsive it should fill the entire screen
           }
          }
```

css

```
<div id="open" class="visible-sm">// contents that are displayed</div>
```

your guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need  to check if your div is visible first not inside else if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a toggle button with the id `#btn` and a corresponding content section with the class `#open` :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
          // Toggle the content on button click
          $("#btn").on("click", function() {
            $("#open").toggle();
          });
        
          // Check if the toggle content is visible initially and on window resize
          function Toggle() {
            if ($("#open").is(":visible")) {
              // Check if the screen size is larger (you can adjust the media query condition)
              if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
                // Apply your styles for larger screens
                $("#open").css("color", "blue");
              }
            } else {
              // Apply styles when the toggle content is not visible
              $("#open").css("color", "initial");
            }
          }
        
          // Initial check on document ready
          Toggle();
        
          // Check on window resize
          $(window).resize(function() {
            Toggle();
          });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
if($('#open').css('display') == 'block')
{
//div is visible
}
else{
//not visible
]
```

Answer (score -1):

**hi, are you trying to like this**

```
  function Toggle() {
          if  ($("#btn").click(function () {

                if ($(window).width() < 991) {
                $("#open").toggle();//this will display my "#open div"
                $("#open").css('display', 'block');
                $("#div").hide();
                 }
                 else {
                   alert('More than 991');
                      }
                }))

          }
```